# Can't clear subplots and replot using twinx

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have something similar to this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, host = plt.subplots()

ax2 = host.twinx()

host.plot([0,1],[0,1],'r')

ax2.plot([1,2],[1,2],'b')

plt.show()

plt.pause(0.0001)

host.clear()

ax2.clear()

host.plot([0,1],[0,1],'r')

ax2.plot([1,2],[1,2],'b')

plt.show()

plt.pause(0.0001)
```

The first time I plot to both subplots, I see both graphs. The second time I post to both subplots, I only see the ax2 graph.

Why is this?

Comment: How do you run this code? As a script? Or line by line? In the console or in IPython?

Comment: It is run within a loop. The idea, being to preserve the figure, but wipe all the data and replot. I have run it within Spyder, within a Linux prompt, as a script, within a function. Same outcome. Basically, the clear functions (i.e. ax2.clear() or ax2.cla()) screw it up. If I let it just stack plots on top of old plots every time I loop through this, it will show both plots. Its only when I try to wipe the previous data.

Comment: I'm having trouble to reproduce this. Can you show the code where you use the loop and where it fails?